# How to handle "by" class returned by using by() function in R

Tags: r, statistics

I am using a by() function in R to run A FUN() on all subsets of a factor. The FUN() returns two numbers as its returning values. The by() function returns a "by" class like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
: 98012
[1] 25.00  0.84
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
: 98301
[1] 5.0 0.6
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'd like to convert this "by" class into an ordinary data.frame so that I can use two returned numbers separately. However, such "by" class cannot be converted into a data.frame. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
df <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, yourByResult)
```

Notice that you need to specify the `cbind.data.frame` otherwise, by using the simple `cbind` the result will be a `matrix` instead of a `data.frame`.

Comment: digEmAll, Thanks for your suggestions. I found another question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407449/for-each-group-summarise-means-for-all-variables-in-dataframe-ddply-split) and it gives in-detailed instructions to use do.call()

Answer (score 2):

I'd say just don't use `by`!

Instead use `ddply` from the plyr package with the syntax

```
ddply(data.frame,splitting-variable,f())
```

the key is that your function needs to take a data.frame and return a data.frame.

Comment: Justin, I checked ddply(). Yes. Using this tool can provide a neat solution. Thanks.